# JSON: parse an array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an HTTP response like this and i want to take only the ID field in reports.
I'm using Jackson, but i can't access to that field.

```
{
    "data": {
        "stixDomainEntities": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "reports": {
                            "edges": [
                                {
                                    "node": {
                                        "id": "136a7d72-c261-4a33-8539-c4b7d43f9497"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For the moment i can access to edges field, but from that point is totally blank, because i have arrays into array. I can also have more that one report with the respective ID, so I need to access to all the eventual fields reports and extract the correspondent IDs... someone could help me?

Comment: The `edges` sub-key is an array, so make sure you are accessing the first item which contains the `node` reference. You need something along the lines of: `response.data.stixDomainEntities.edges.get(0).node.reports.edges.get(0).node.id`

Comment: @ansem90 did the posted answer helped you ? let me know in case u need further help.